# What is the role of crt* files in linking?

Tags: linux, gcc

We have several crt* files like `/build/csu/crt0.o` or `/build/csu/crti.o` or `/build/csu/crtn.o` or `/build/csu/crtbegin.o` or `` `/build/csu/crtendS.o `` used with gcc while building.

Can someone explain me clearly what is the role and functionality of these files?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the object code file ctr1.o do in the gcc compiler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/886585/what-does-the-object-code-file-ctr1-o-do-in-the-gcc-compiler)

Comment: @Mat: That is only for crt1.o. A very small subset of entire thing.

Comment: Who voted as close? And without stating the reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate is a close vote. The automatic link comment is self-explanatory. If you read that question's answers, you'll get information about pretty much all of them (the link provided by phihag is linked there also).

Comment: @Mat: The link provided by philag is infact the answer to my question, since it provides all the crt*. The link does not explicitly go to crt1, which was infact asked in the question you indicated. At the same time, having a knowledge of crt1.o does not suffice for all crt*'s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crt files contain the runtime - that's the code that calls your `main` function, handles program termination, and some instructions on how to lay out functions. Here's a [mini FAQ](http://dev.gentoo.org/~vapier/crt.txt).

Comment: So why normally in program compilation it is not provided? And our program compiles fine even without that?

Comment: @kingsmasher1 These files are implicitely linked (and used during compilation if you're compiling to machine code) by your compiler. They do contain some methods you could call (starting with underlines), but doing so would be a very bad idea, as these methods are internal and therefore should not be used, and subject to change between glibc increments.

Comment: So it means, if we are explicitly compiling for our own library (other than glibc) then the linking to crt*'s is required.

Comment: @ĸingsmasher1 no, quite the contrary. Unless you're writing a **compiler** or **linker**, you don't have to worry about it. View the `ctr*` more like a part of the compiler executable.